# How to update users facebook profile status from my rails web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook

in my rails web application I am implementing Facebook connectivity. I want that whenever user updates his/her status on my site his/her facebook status should also be updated. Is there any working rails application for this? 
Please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) as well also accomplishes what the koala gem does .

Though to update on a user to user basis you'll need to have some sort of login system in place.  In that case I'd look at [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) using omniauth to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) gem which acts as a client to the Facebook graph API and does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I use devise + omniauth for authentication and getting the right access token. 
I use Koala for updating + reading information.